# Process SSAS Tabular Cube - Snowflake ODBC Connection Using OAuth

Tags: odbc, ssas, tabular

Currently I have SSAS tabular model connects to SQL Server to process the cube, the id used to connect has windows authentication enabled so no stored password. Cube processing is automated through powershell scripts using Invoke-ProcessTable Module.

Now sql server datasource is getting moved to snowflake. So the connectivity need to switched to Snowflake ODBC driver and the only authentication allowed by the firm is OAuth.

**Question**:

1. How to establish connectivity from SSAS to Snowflake using Snowflake ODBC driver with OAuth in powershell. I understand from documentation that OAuth authentication has to go through IdP(Identity Provider) which is ping federate and authentication happens through tokens, connection should start with bearer token and continuously refreshed with refresh token to keep the connectivity.
2. Whats the powershell module should use to process the table?
   **Invoke-ProcessTable** - is looks SQL Server module and don't see any support of passing connection string.
   **Invoke-ASCmd** - Can I make use of this module, does any one have suggestion to pass the Snowflake ODBC connection with OAuth tokens?

Am at early stages of figuring out this use case. Please let me know if any questions or direction for me to try out and get back to you guys for you to suggest better.